# if $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{x_i} = 1$, how do you choose the $x_i$'s such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{x_i^2}$ is minimized?

Tags: optimization, summation

if $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{x_i} = 1$, how do you choose the $x_i$'s such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{x_i^2}$ is minimized.

I have an intuition that each $x_i = \frac{1}{n}$, but I don't know how to prove it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$0\leq \sum_{k=1}^n\left(x_k-\frac1n\right)^2=\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2\right)-\frac1n$$ with equality if and only if $x_k=\tfrac1n$ for $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused where you get this inequality from, could you give a reference or a quick explanation? Thanks!

Comment: sum of squares is non-negative. For the equality, just expand and use $\sum_kx_k=1$.

Comment: Oh, duh. What an elegant proof! thanks WimC

Comment: Lovely! The way it's written ties it in nicely to the $E(X^2)\ge E(X)^2$ result in probability/statistics (the one that uses $Var X \ge 0$).

Answer (score 6):

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

$$1 = \left|\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i\right|^2 \leqslant \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2\sum_{i = 1}^n (1)^2 = n\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2.$$

Hence,

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2 \geqslant \frac1{n},$$

and the minimum is attained when $x_i = 1/n$.

Answer (score 4):

Your intution is correct, and you can prove it using a Lagrange multiplier: Setting the derivative of $\sum_ix_i^2-\lambda(\sum_ix_i-1)$ with respect to $x_j$ to zero yields $2x_j=\lambda$, and then your result follows from the normalisation condition.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the origin by $O$, and let $H$ be the hyperplane given by $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 0$.  This question is asking for the point on $H$ closest to $O$.

The line $L$ given by $x_1=x_2=\cdots  = x_n$ passes through $O$ and is perpendicular to $H$.  By the Pythagorean Theorem, the shortest distance from $O$ to $H$ lies along the perpendicular.

Since the intersection of $L$ with $H$ is $x_i = 1/n$, this is the closest point.

Answer (score 0):

$$1=1^2=\left(\sum_ix_i\right)^2=\sum_ix_i^2+\sum_{i<j}2x_ix_j\le\sum_ix_i^2+\sum_{i<j}(x_i^2+x_j^2)=n\sum_ix_i^2$$

where the inequality comes from the fact that $(x-y)^2=x^2-2xy+y^2\ge0$ (basically AM-GM inequality). We thus arrive at our result:

$$\sum_ix_i^2\ge\frac{1}{n}$$